# Como deletar arquivo xml com c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, xml

Estou usando esse código para criar o arquivo XML, mas queria saber como faço para deletar um sem precisar ir na pasta e deletar manualmente.

```
     DataTable table = new DataTable("tbl");
        table.Columns.Add("CaminhoR1", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("NomeTblR1", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("ConcR1", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("CaminhoR2", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("NomeTblR2", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("ConcR2", typeof(string));

        table.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, comboBox1.Text, textBox4.Text, textBox5.Text, comboBox2.Text);

        dgvDadosConexao.DataSource = table;          
        table.WriteXml(@"C:\Users\Felipe\source\repos\teste\teste\conexões\" + cmbConex.Text + ".xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

Comment: Ainda não entendi porq estou sendo negativado, se tem algum problema ou erro na pergunta, não podem comentar não?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o [File.Delete()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-BR/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=net-5.0)

```
System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Users\Felipe\source\repos\teste\teste\conexões\" + cmbConex.Text + ".xml");
```

Geralmente se valida se o arquivo existe para evitar um erro, mas no seu código como criou o arquivo ele vai estar lá.

Fique atento para não estar usando o arquivo, ou também irá gerar um erro.